# Enviar convite para reunião com PHPMailer

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

Ao criar um novo evento no calendário, automaticamente envia um e-mail ao responsável por esse evento com a informação de que foi marcado um novo evento desta forma:

```
try {
    $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password,
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        //echo 'Conexao efetuada com sucesso!';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
      if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['contact']) && isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end']) && isset($_POST['color'])){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];

    require ("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require ("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

# Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

# Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; # Endereço do servidor SMTP, na WebHS basta usar localhost caso a conta de email esteja na mesma máquina de onde esta a correr este código, caso contrário altere para o seu desejado ex: mail.nomedoseudominio.pt
$mail->Port = 587; // Porta TCP para a conexão
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // Utiliza TLS Automaticamente se disponível
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; # Usar autenticação SMTP - Sim
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'; # Login de e-mail
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx'; // # Password do e-mail
# Define o remetente (você)
$mail->From = "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"; # Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "xxxxxxxxx"; // Seu nome
# Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.xx', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'); # Os campos podem ser substituidos por variáveis
#$mail->AddAddress('webmaster@nomedoseudominio.pt'); # Caso queira receber uma copia
#$mail->AddCC('pessoa2@dominio.pt', 'Pessoa Nome 2'); # Copia
#$mail->AddBCC('pessoa3@dominio.pt', 'Pessoa Nome 3'); # Cópia Oculta
# Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->IsHTML(true); # Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
#$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; # Charset da mensagem (opcional)
# Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject = "Marcações"; # Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "Informo que tem uma nova marcação.
<html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <h2>Marcação</h2>


                          <tr>
                            <th>Nome: ".$title."</th><p></br>
                            <th>Contacto: ".$contact."</th><p></br>
                            <th>Data Inicio: ".$start."</th><p></br>
                            <th>Data Fim: ".$end."</th><p></br>
                          </tr>

                        </body>
                        </html>";
$mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, somente Texto! \r\n :)";

# Define os anexos (opcional)
#$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "documento.pdf"); # Insere um anexo
# Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send(); 
# Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO eventsLar(title, contact, start, end, color, colaborador) values ('$title', '$contact', '$start', '$end', '$color', 'xxxxxx xxxxxxx')";

    echo $sql;

    $query = $bdd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
     die ('Erreur prepare');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
    if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Erreur execute');
    }

}
```

Mas pretendia, que ao enviar o email, envie como convite para que ao aceitar marque logo também na agenda do e-mail de quem recebe.

Answer (score -2):

Estive mexendo com iCal recentemente, infelizmente pesquisei muito e não achei um jeito de ser possível que o convite seja aceito automaticamente. É necessário o aceito do cliente porque se não seria usado esses eventos para spam.

No meu caso eu achei mais viável a sincronização de agenda ao invés do envio de convites

Edit: perdão não vi que você não esta usando iCal

Para enviar como convite precisa utilizar o formato iCal

Basta utilizar o exemplo abaixo dentro da função iCal do PHPMailer

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ZContent.net//Zap Calendar 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Abraham Lincoln
UID:c7614cff-3549-4a00-9152-d25cc1fe077d
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:jsmith@example.com
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=2;BYMONTHDAY=12
DTSTART:20080212
DTEND:20080213
DTSTAMP:20150421T141403
CATEGORIES:U.S. Presidents,Civil War People
LOCATION:Hodgenville\, Kentucky
GEO:37.5739497;-85.7399606
DESCRIPTION:Born February 12\, 1809\nSixteenth President (1861-1865)\n\n\n
 \nhttp://AmericanHistoryCalendar.com
URL:http://americanhistorycalendar.com/peoplecalendar/1,328-abraham-lincol
 n
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Edite com a sua necessidade e para mais informações procure sobre iCal

**Edit 2:**

Para mandar convites por email é necessários enviar na padronização ical como descrito acima. Para adaptá-lo ao seu convite é necessário modificar os valores dos campos, onde:

`dtstart` e `dtend` referem-se às data de inicio e fim
`uid` é o identificador único do evento no calendário
`attendees` os participantes

Para mais detalhes gere um evento no calendário do Outlook e envie o e-mail, baixe o ics e veja os atributos gerados.

Exemplo de utilização com PHP Mailer:

```
// ...

//Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('invite.ics');         // Add attachments

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'treste7';
    $mail->Body    = 'teste';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->ContentType = 'application/ics';


    $cal = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//bobbin v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100701T080000Z
DTEND:20100701T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:jsmith@example.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 1
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100701T120000Z
DTEND:20100701T130000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003b@yoursever.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 2
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';

// Method: REQUEST, CANCEL
// Status: CONFIRMED, CANCELLED
    $mail->Ical = $cal;
    $mail->send();
```

Onde o conteúdo da variável `$cal` é o mesmo do que deve estar no anexo invite.ics, pois alguns emails necessitam do conteudo em anexo.

Comment: ????? a pergunta foi "Mas pretendia, que ao enviar o email, envie como convite para que ao aceitar marque logo também na agenda do e-mail de quem recebe.".

Para enviar email como convite para calendário é necessário utilizar o padrão ical.

Comment: Realmente, se é o que está dizendo, está tão confusa que nem havia percebido. Dê uma melhorada na resposta, para facilitar quem nunca ouviu falar do `iCal`, que ele funciona com o PHPMailer, dê um exemplo de como chamar esses dados no PHPMailer, etc.. ✌️